# Get (or write) class files for the classes in the DynamicClassLoader

Tags: clojure

Is there any way to find/write the class files for the classes in the `DynamicClassLoader`?

```clj
  (let [f #(+ 1 %)
        cls (class f)
        cl (.getClassLoader cls)]
    
    (println (.getName cls)) ; => my.project.namespace$eval123$f__4321

    ;; Do something here to get a path to a class file
    ;; .../my/project/namespace/eval123$f__4321.class

    )
```

Comment: If there were a way of doing what you are asking for, what would you use it for?

Comment: Distributing computing frameworks (in my case, Apache Spark) have mechanisms to send class files to the cluster so that worker nodes can properly deserialize and execute the distributed code. In oder to distribute Clojure code over Spark when not AOT compiling the project, I need to send Class files to the Spark cluster for any class that was not present when the workers were started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After browsing the Clojure source code I found a compiler var that does exactly what I want. I don't know if I would recommend this approach, but it was been working well for me so far.

```clj
(.bindRoot Compiler/COMPILE_FILES true)
```

This will write `.class` files to the path under `*compile-path*`.

Answer (score 2):

Those classes are never written, and there is no mechanism to, from a Class object, discover a series of bytes that would have produced that class. As far as I know, the best you could do would be to use JVM instrumentation tools to record the bytes of the class as they are compiled. I'm no expert on how this works, but [`no-disassemble`](https://github.com/gtrak/no.disassemble) does it somehow; you could either use it, or do it yourself using a similar approach.